# Problema finalizando carrito

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy armando una tienda, se compone de productos, usuarios, un carrito, utilizando varios ejemplos y metiendo mano realice algunas modificaciones, pero me encuentro trabado en lo siguiente:
Al finalizar el carrito quiero un botón que lo cierre y le permita al usuario generar otro carrito separado, pero no logro hacer algo que funcione, alguna sugerencia/ayuda? les paso el código:

**views/carts/show.html.erb:**

```
<div class="cart_item">
    <%= render "partials/cart_item" %>
</div>
```

**views/partials/_cart_item.html.erb:**

```
<% if !@order_item.nil? && @order_item.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
        <% @order_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<br/>
<h3>Carrito de compras</h3>
<br/>
<div>
    <%= link_to "Atras", root_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% if @order_items.size>0 %>
    <% @order_items.each do |item| %>
    <div>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h3><%= item.product.title %></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <%= form_for(item, remote: true) do |f| %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: item.product.id %>
                        <h5><%= item.product.price %></h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: item.quantity.to_i, min: 1, class: 'form-control' %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <%= f.submit "Modificar", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                            <%= link_to  "Eliminar", item, method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-danger'  %>
                        </div>
                        <span>Total Price: <%= item.total_price %></span>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
      <li><%= link_to "Finalizar compra", class: "fa fa-sign-out" %></li>
    </div>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

**models/order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  before_save :set_data


  def subtotal
    order_items.collect {|order_item| order_item.valid? ? (order_item.unit_price*order_item.quantity) : 0}.sum
  end
  def total
    order_items.collect {|order_item| order_item.valid? ? (subtotal) : 0}.sum
  end
  # def usuario
  #   current_user.id
  # end
  private
    def set_data
      self[:subtotal] = subtotal
      self[:total] = total
      self[:status] = "to_checkout"
      # self[:user_id] = usuario
    end
end
```

Les dejo el **rar** [aquí](https://app.box.com/s/5ejkpsks2su217mlfejeqe57q94xmkup) con el proyecto por si necesitan mas información:

Comment: Hola paulo, en lugar de dejar todo el código e incluso una proyecto completo que dificilmente alguien se va a dedicar a ejecutar, mejor concentra tu esfuerzo en poner solo el código donde ocurre el error. Lee  [mcve]

Comment: ganas reputacion o algo realizando respuestas que no contribuyen a nada? despues de mucho tiempo decidi responderte, si lees el encabezado indica que la ayuda va por el lado que no se como realizar una accion, no que de error. Gracias por tu "no ayuda".

Comment: Al contrario se gana reputación con preguntas y respuestas que si contribuyen al bien común de todos los usuarios. Lamentablemente tu pregunta no ha causado la atención o impacto deseado debido a que falta mejorarla. Si lees el artículo que te deje, sabrás como mejorar la para que alguien se interese por tu pregunta. De nada

Comment: Ten en cuenta que mi aporte no es con una respuesta debido a que no manejo tanto ruby sino con indicarte el camino para mejorar tu pregunta. De pasada te recomiendo que leas también esto. [Stack Overflow culture](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/)